# Homebrew installation failed

Tags: macos, homebrew

I was trying to re-install homebrew on my Mac. I used the following command.

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

I got the following error. Could someone help me with what to do here?

```
==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password).
Password:
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R aryan:admin /usr/local/Homebrew
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
HEAD is now at 227445ece Merge pull request #11288 from Homebrew/update-manpage
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Error: Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core failed!
Failed during: /usr/local/bin/brew update --force --quiet
```

Comment: Homebrew's page uses the following: `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`

Comment: So, I updated the re-installed the "xcode-select install" and then tried running the command. But I am getting the same error.

Comment: @agarza I just tried that too. I got the same error exactly. I just tried **brew update-reset**. that command points to master itself. So am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you tried [uninstalling](https://github.com/homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew) first?

Comment: @JBallin I ran the command **/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"** and it was uninstalled. As I mentioned in my previous comment, I removed the **HomeBrew** files from **/usr/local** and it is all good.

Comment: after you fix this perhaps you can install brew with these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381128/installing-homebrew-on-os-x

Answer (score 12):

I removed the HomeBrew files by running the following command. After that, I ran the installation as mentioned in the above post. It all worked fine. I was able to install all the packages I need.

```
# Intel systems
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/homebrew

# M1/M2 system
sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew
```

Comment: after this do what they say here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381128/installing-homebrew-on-os-x

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem. The solution is just to remove your git configuration from your mac.

Command:

```
rm -rf ~/.gitconfig
```

After executing the command try to install brew. Command:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

After installing homebrew install the brew git command:

```
brew install git
```

then configure your GitHub profile.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Thanks for the answer. What does configure GitHub profile involve. Will homebrew not work?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sure, the homebrew will work. But in my case, I miss configured my GitHub profile, I set my git repo to inside a local folder in my mac. So when I run the install command of brew then it's throwing me an error that homebrews default but does not exist. If your Girhub profile is already configured globally, then it's okay.

Comment: Adding that to the answer would be super if you wanted to elaborate - thanks so much for replying!