# Homebrew installation failed on macOS 12.2.1

Tags: macos, install, homebrew

I am trying to install Homebrew under macOS Monterey 12.2.1 but I get:

```
hmerovich@Horacios-MacBook-Pro ~ % /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password)...
==> This script will install:
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/opt/homebrew/share/doc/homebrew
/opt/homebrew/share/man/man1/brew.1
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/opt/homebrew/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/opt/homebrew
==> HOMEBREW_BREW_GIT_REMOTE is set to a non-default URL:
... will be used as the Homebrew/brew Git remote.
==> HOMEBREW_CORE_GIT_REMOTE is set to a non-default URL:
... will be used as the Homebrew/homebrew-core Git remote.

Press RETURN/ENTER to continue or any other key to abort:
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R hmerovich:admin /opt/homebrew
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
fatal: '...' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Failed during: git fetch --force origin
```

Any help to solve the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Homebrew installation failed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/419724/homebrew-installation-failed?rq=1)?

Comment: Please use the CODE formatting to make your error message more readable! Did you follow the instructions on http://brew.sh?