# Unable to install Homebrew on M1 MacBook Air

Tags: macos, terminal, install, homebrew, apple-silicon

I am unable to install homebrew. I had homebrew installed on my previous Intel mac, and when I migrated to my new device the program remained in the Intel location. I was attempting to uninstall and re-install under /opt/homebrew. The installer fails at the same point every time. I've scoured the internet for solutions and none have worked. The installer keeps throwing the same error. Here is the command I've been running:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

And here is the installer output:

```
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/install -d -o root -g wheel -m 0755 /opt/homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /opt/homebrew/bin /opt/homebrew/etc /opt/homebrew/include /opt/homebrew/lib /opt/homebrew/sbin /opt/homebrew/share /opt/homebrew/var /opt/homebrew/opt /opt/homebrew/share/zsh /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew/linked /opt/homebrew/Cellar /opt/homebrew/Caskroom /opt/homebrew/Frameworks
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod ug=rwx /opt/homebrew/bin /opt/homebrew/etc /opt/homebrew/include /opt/homebrew/lib /opt/homebrew/sbin /opt/homebrew/share /opt/homebrew/var /opt/homebrew/opt /opt/homebrew/share/zsh /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew/linked /opt/homebrew/Cellar /opt/homebrew/Caskroom /opt/homebrew/Frameworks
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod go-w /opt/homebrew/share/zsh /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown ericrumsey /opt/homebrew/bin /opt/homebrew/etc /opt/homebrew/include /opt/homebrew/lib /opt/homebrew/sbin /opt/homebrew/share /opt/homebrew/var /opt/homebrew/opt /opt/homebrew/share/zsh /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew/linked /opt/homebrew/Cellar /opt/homebrew/Caskroom /opt/homebrew/Frameworks
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/chgrp admin /opt/homebrew/bin /opt/homebrew/etc /opt/homebrew/include /opt/homebrew/lib /opt/homebrew/sbin /opt/homebrew/share /opt/homebrew/var /opt/homebrew/opt /opt/homebrew/share/zsh /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew/linked /opt/homebrew/Cellar /opt/homebrew/Caskroom /opt/homebrew/Frameworks
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R ericrumsey:admin /opt/homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /Users/ericrumsey/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod g+rwx /Users/ericrumsey/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R ericrumsey /Users/ericrumsey/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
remote: Enumerating objects: 233412, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (731/731), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (435/435), done.
remote: Total 233412 (delta 330), reused 633 (delta 284), pack-reused 232681
Receiving objects: 100% (233412/233412), 67.83 MiB | 1.19 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (171224/171224), done.
From https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
 * [new branch]          master     -> origin/master
 * [new tag]             0.1        -> 0.1
 * [new tag]             0.2        -> 0.2
 * [new tag]             0.3        -> 0.3
 * [new tag]             0.4        -> 0.4
 * [new tag]             0.5        -> 0.5
 * [new tag]             0.6        -> 0.6
 * [new tag]             0.7        -> 0.7
 * [new tag]             0.7.1      -> 0.7.1
 * [new tag]             0.8        -> 0.8
 * [new tag]             0.8.1      -> 0.8.1
 * [new tag]             0.9        -> 0.9
 * [new tag]             0.9.1      -> 0.9.1
 * [new tag]             0.9.2      -> 0.9.2
 * [new tag]             0.9.3      -> 0.9.3
 * [new tag]             0.9.4      -> 0.9.4
 * [new tag]             0.9.5      -> 0.9.5
 * [new tag]             0.9.8      -> 0.9.8
 * [new tag]             0.9.9      -> 0.9.9
 * [new tag]             1.0.0      -> 1.0.0
 * [new tag]             1.0.1      -> 1.0.1
 * [new tag]             1.0.2      -> 1.0.2
 * [new tag]             1.0.3      -> 1.0.3
 * [new tag]             1.0.4      -> 1.0.4
 * [new tag]             1.0.5      -> 1.0.5
 * [new tag]             1.0.6      -> 1.0.6
 * [new tag]             1.0.7      -> 1.0.7
 * [new tag]             1.0.8      -> 1.0.8
 * [new tag]             1.0.9      -> 1.0.9
 * [new tag]             1.1.0      -> 1.1.0
 * [new tag]             1.1.1      -> 1.1.1
 * [new tag]             1.1.10     -> 1.1.10
 * [new tag]             1.1.11     -> 1.1.11
 * [new tag]             1.1.12     -> 1.1.12
 * [new tag]             1.1.13     -> 1.1.13
 * [new tag]             1.1.2      -> 1.1.2
 * [new tag]             1.1.3      -> 1.1.3
 * [new tag]             1.1.4      -> 1.1.4
 * [new tag]             1.1.5      -> 1.1.5
 * [new tag]             1.1.6      -> 1.1.6
 * [new tag]             1.1.7      -> 1.1.7
 * [new tag]             1.1.8      -> 1.1.8
 * [new tag]             1.1.9      -> 1.1.9
 * [new tag]             1.2.0      -> 1.2.0
 * [new tag]             1.2.1      -> 1.2.1
 * [new tag]             1.2.2      -> 1.2.2
 * [new tag]             1.2.3      -> 1.2.3
 * [new tag]             1.2.4      -> 1.2.4
 * [new tag]             1.2.5      -> 1.2.5
 * [new tag]             1.2.6      -> 1.2.6
 * [new tag]             1.3.0      -> 1.3.0
 * [new tag]             1.3.1      -> 1.3.1
 * [new tag]             1.3.2      -> 1.3.2
 * [new tag]             1.3.3      -> 1.3.3
 * [new tag]             1.3.4      -> 1.3.4
 * [new tag]             1.3.5      -> 1.3.5
 * [new tag]             1.3.6      -> 1.3.6
 * [new tag]             1.3.7      -> 1.3.7
 * [new tag]             1.3.8      -> 1.3.8
 * [new tag]             1.3.9      -> 1.3.9
 * [new tag]             1.4.0      -> 1.4.0
 * [new tag]             1.4.1      -> 1.4.1
 * [new tag]             1.4.2      -> 1.4.2
 * [new tag]             1.4.3      -> 1.4.3
 * [new tag]             1.5.0      -> 1.5.0
 * [new tag]             1.5.1      -> 1.5.1
 * [new tag]             1.5.10     -> 1.5.10
 * [new tag]             1.5.11     -> 1.5.11
 * [new tag]             1.5.12     -> 1.5.12
 * [new tag]             1.5.13     -> 1.5.13
 * [new tag]             1.5.14     -> 1.5.14
 * [new tag]             1.5.2      -> 1.5.2
 * [new tag]             1.5.3      -> 1.5.3
 * [new tag]             1.5.4      -> 1.5.4
 * [new tag]             1.5.5      -> 1.5.5
 * [new tag]             1.5.6      -> 1.5.6
 * [new tag]             1.5.7      -> 1.5.7
 * [new tag]             1.5.8      -> 1.5.8
 * [new tag]             1.5.9      -> 1.5.9
 * [new tag]             1.6.0      -> 1.6.0
 * [new tag]             1.6.1      -> 1.6.1
 * [new tag]             1.6.10     -> 1.6.10
 * [new tag]             1.6.11     -> 1.6.11
 * [new tag]             1.6.12     -> 1.6.12
 * [new tag]             1.6.13     -> 1.6.13
 * [new tag]             1.6.14     -> 1.6.14
 * [new tag]             1.6.15     -> 1.6.15
 * [new tag]             1.6.16     -> 1.6.16
 * [new tag]             1.6.17     -> 1.6.17
 * [new tag]             1.6.2      -> 1.6.2
 * [new tag]             1.6.3      -> 1.6.3
 * [new tag]             1.6.4      -> 1.6.4
 * [new tag]             1.6.5      -> 1.6.5
 * [new tag]             1.6.6      -> 1.6.6
 * [new tag]             1.6.7      -> 1.6.7
 * [new tag]             1.6.8      -> 1.6.8
 * [new tag]             1.6.9      -> 1.6.9
 * [new tag]             1.7.0      -> 1.7.0
 * [new tag]             1.7.1      -> 1.7.1
 * [new tag]             1.7.2      -> 1.7.2
 * [new tag]             1.7.3      -> 1.7.3
 * [new tag]             1.7.4      -> 1.7.4
 * [new tag]             1.7.5      -> 1.7.5
 * [new tag]             1.7.6      -> 1.7.6
 * [new tag]             1.7.7      -> 1.7.7
 * [new tag]             1.8.0      -> 1.8.0
 * [new tag]             1.8.1      -> 1.8.1
 * [new tag]             1.8.2      -> 1.8.2
 * [new tag]             1.8.3      -> 1.8.3
 * [new tag]             1.8.4      -> 1.8.4
 * [new tag]             1.8.5      -> 1.8.5
 * [new tag]             1.8.6      -> 1.8.6
 * [new tag]             1.9.0      -> 1.9.0
 * [new tag]             1.9.1      -> 1.9.1
 * [new tag]             1.9.2      -> 1.9.2
 * [new tag]             1.9.3      -> 1.9.3
 * [new tag]             2.0.0      -> 2.0.0
 * [new tag]             2.0.1      -> 2.0.1
 * [new tag]             2.0.2      -> 2.0.2
 * [new tag]             2.0.3      -> 2.0.3
 * [new tag]             2.0.4      -> 2.0.4
 * [new tag]             2.0.5      -> 2.0.5
 * [new tag]             2.0.6      -> 2.0.6
 * [new tag]             2.1.0      -> 2.1.0
 * [new tag]             2.1.1      -> 2.1.1
 * [new tag]             2.1.10     -> 2.1.10
 * [new tag]             2.1.11     -> 2.1.11
 * [new tag]             2.1.12     -> 2.1.12
 * [new tag]             2.1.13     -> 2.1.13
 * [new tag]             2.1.14     -> 2.1.14
 * [new tag]             2.1.15     -> 2.1.15
 * [new tag]             2.1.16     -> 2.1.16
 * [new tag]             2.1.2      -> 2.1.2
 * [new tag]             2.1.3      -> 2.1.3
 * [new tag]             2.1.4      -> 2.1.4
 * [new tag]             2.1.5      -> 2.1.5
 * [new tag]             2.1.6      -> 2.1.6
 * [new tag]             2.1.7      -> 2.1.7
 * [new tag]             2.1.8      -> 2.1.8
 * [new tag]             2.1.9      -> 2.1.9
 * [new tag]             2.2.0      -> 2.2.0
 * [new tag]             2.2.1      -> 2.2.1
 * [new tag]             2.2.10     -> 2.2.10
 * [new tag]             2.2.11     -> 2.2.11
 * [new tag]             2.2.12     -> 2.2.12
 * [new tag]             2.2.13     -> 2.2.13
 * [new tag]             2.2.14     -> 2.2.14
 * [new tag]             2.2.15     -> 2.2.15
 * [new tag]             2.2.16     -> 2.2.16
 * [new tag]             2.2.17     -> 2.2.17
 * [new tag]             2.2.2      -> 2.2.2
 * [new tag]             2.2.3      -> 2.2.3
 * [new tag]             2.2.4      -> 2.2.4
 * [new tag]             2.2.5      -> 2.2.5
 * [new tag]             2.2.6      -> 2.2.6
 * [new tag]             2.2.7      -> 2.2.7
 * [new tag]             2.2.8      -> 2.2.8
 * [new tag]             2.2.9      -> 2.2.9
 * [new tag]             2.3.0      -> 2.3.0
 * [new tag]             2.4.0      -> 2.4.0
 * [new tag]             2.4.1      -> 2.4.1
 * [new tag]             2.4.10     -> 2.4.10
 * [new tag]             2.4.11     -> 2.4.11
 * [new tag]             2.4.12     -> 2.4.12
 * [new tag]             2.4.13     -> 2.4.13
 * [new tag]             2.4.14     -> 2.4.14
 * [new tag]             2.4.15     -> 2.4.15
 * [new tag]             2.4.16     -> 2.4.16
 * [new tag]             2.4.2      -> 2.4.2
 * [new tag]             2.4.3      -> 2.4.3
 * [new tag]             2.4.4      -> 2.4.4
 * [new tag]             2.4.5      -> 2.4.5
 * [new tag]             2.4.6      -> 2.4.6
 * [new tag]             2.4.7      -> 2.4.7
 * [new tag]             2.4.8      -> 2.4.8
 * [new tag]             2.4.9      -> 2.4.9
 * [new tag]             2.5.0      -> 2.5.0
 * [new tag]             2.5.1      -> 2.5.1
 * [new tag]             2.5.10     -> 2.5.10
 * [new tag]             2.5.11     -> 2.5.11
 * [new tag]             2.5.12     -> 2.5.12
 * [new tag]             2.5.2      -> 2.5.2
 * [new tag]             2.5.3      -> 2.5.3
 * [new tag]             2.5.4      -> 2.5.4
 * [new tag]             2.5.5      -> 2.5.5
 * [new tag]             2.5.6      -> 2.5.6
 * [new tag]             2.5.7      -> 2.5.7
 * [new tag]             2.5.8      -> 2.5.8
 * [new tag]             2.5.9      -> 2.5.9
 * [new tag]             2.6.0      -> 2.6.0
 * [new tag]             2.6.1      -> 2.6.1
 * [new tag]             2.6.2      -> 2.6.2
 * [new tag]             2.7.0      -> 2.7.0
 * [new tag]             2.7.1      -> 2.7.1
 * [new tag]             2.7.2      -> 2.7.2
 * [new tag]             2.7.3      -> 2.7.3
 * [new tag]             2.7.4      -> 2.7.4
 * [new tag]             2.7.5      -> 2.7.5
 * [new tag]             2.7.6      -> 2.7.6
 * [new tag]             2.7.7      -> 2.7.7
 * [new tag]             3.0.0      -> 3.0.0
 * [new tag]             3.0.1      -> 3.0.1
 * [new tag]             3.0.10     -> 3.0.10
 * [new tag]             3.0.11     -> 3.0.11
 * [new tag]             3.0.2      -> 3.0.2
 * [new tag]             3.0.3      -> 3.0.3
 * [new tag]             3.0.4      -> 3.0.4
 * [new tag]             3.0.5      -> 3.0.5
 * [new tag]             3.0.6      -> 3.0.6
 * [new tag]             3.0.7      -> 3.0.7
 * [new tag]             3.0.8      -> 3.0.8
 * [new tag]             3.0.9      -> 3.0.9
 * [new tag]             3.1.0      -> 3.1.0
 * [new tag]             3.1.1      -> 3.1.1
 * [new tag]             3.1.10     -> 3.1.10
 * [new tag]             3.1.11     -> 3.1.11
 * [new tag]             3.1.12     -> 3.1.12
 * [new tag]             3.1.2      -> 3.1.2
 * [new tag]             3.1.3      -> 3.1.3
 * [new tag]             3.1.4      -> 3.1.4
 * [new tag]             3.1.5      -> 3.1.5
 * [new tag]             3.1.6      -> 3.1.6
 * [new tag]             3.1.7      -> 3.1.7
 * [new tag]             3.1.8      -> 3.1.8
 * [new tag]             3.1.9      -> 3.1.9
 * [new tag]             3.2.0      -> 3.2.0
 * [new tag]             3.2.1      -> 3.2.1
 * [new tag]             3.2.10     -> 3.2.10
 * [new tag]             3.2.11     -> 3.2.11
 * [new tag]             3.2.12     -> 3.2.12
 * [new tag]             3.2.13     -> 3.2.13
 * [new tag]             3.2.14     -> 3.2.14
 * [new tag]             3.2.15     -> 3.2.15
 * [new tag]             3.2.16     -> 3.2.16
 * [new tag]             3.2.17     -> 3.2.17
 * [new tag]             3.2.2      -> 3.2.2
 * [new tag]             3.2.3      -> 3.2.3
 * [new tag]             3.2.4      -> 3.2.4
 * [new tag]             3.2.5      -> 3.2.5
 * [new tag]             3.2.6      -> 3.2.6
 * [new tag]             3.2.7      -> 3.2.7
 * [new tag]             3.2.8      -> 3.2.8
 * [new tag]             3.2.9      -> 3.2.9
 * [new tag]             3.3.0      -> 3.3.0
 * [new tag]             3.3.1      -> 3.3.1
 * [new tag]             3.3.10     -> 3.3.10
 * [new tag]             3.3.11     -> 3.3.11
 * [new tag]             3.3.12     -> 3.3.12
 * [new tag]             3.3.13     -> 3.3.13
 * [new tag]             3.3.14     -> 3.3.14
 * [new tag]             3.3.15     -> 3.3.15
 * [new tag]             3.3.16     -> 3.3.16
 * [new tag]             3.3.2      -> 3.3.2
 * [new tag]             3.3.3      -> 3.3.3
 * [new tag]             3.3.4      -> 3.3.4
 * [new tag]             3.3.5      -> 3.3.5
 * [new tag]             3.3.6      -> 3.3.6
 * [new tag]             3.3.7      -> 3.3.7
 * [new tag]             3.3.8      -> 3.3.8
 * [new tag]             3.3.9      -> 3.3.9
 * [new tag]             3.4.0      -> 3.4.0
 * [new tag]             3.4.1      -> 3.4.1
 * [new tag]             3.4.10     -> 3.4.10
 * [new tag]             3.4.11     -> 3.4.11
 * [new tag]             3.4.2      -> 3.4.2
 * [new tag]             3.4.3      -> 3.4.3
 * [new tag]             3.4.4      -> 3.4.4
 * [new tag]             3.4.5      -> 3.4.5
 * [new tag]             3.4.6      -> 3.4.6
 * [new tag]             3.4.7      -> 3.4.7
 * [new tag]             3.4.8      -> 3.4.8
 * [new tag]             3.4.9      -> 3.4.9
 * [new tag]             3.5.0      -> 3.5.0
 * [new tag]             3.5.1      -> 3.5.1
 * [new tag]             3.5.10     -> 3.5.10
 * [new tag]             3.5.2      -> 3.5.2
 * [new tag]             3.5.3      -> 3.5.3
 * [new tag]             3.5.4      -> 3.5.4
 * [new tag]             3.5.5      -> 3.5.5
 * [new tag]             3.5.6      -> 3.5.6
 * [new tag]             3.5.7      -> 3.5.7
 * [new tag]             3.5.8      -> 3.5.8
 * [new tag]             3.5.9      -> 3.5.9
 * [new tag]             3.6.0      -> 3.6.0
 * [new tag]             3.6.1      -> 3.6.1
 * [new tag]             3.6.10     -> 3.6.10
 * [new tag]             3.6.11     -> 3.6.11
 * [new tag]             3.6.12     -> 3.6.12
 * [new tag]             3.6.13     -> 3.6.13
 * [new tag]             3.6.14     -> 3.6.14
 * [new tag]             3.6.15     -> 3.6.15
 * [new tag]             3.6.16     -> 3.6.16
 * [new tag]             3.6.17     -> 3.6.17
 * [new tag]             3.6.18     -> 3.6.18
 * [new tag]             3.6.19     -> 3.6.19
 * [new tag]             3.6.2      -> 3.6.2
 * [new tag]             3.6.20     -> 3.6.20
 * [new tag]             3.6.21     -> 3.6.21
 * [new tag]             3.6.3      -> 3.6.3
 * [new tag]             3.6.4      -> 3.6.4
 * [new tag]             3.6.5      -> 3.6.5
 * [new tag]             3.6.6      -> 3.6.6
 * [new tag]             3.6.7      -> 3.6.7
 * [new tag]             3.6.8      -> 3.6.8
 * [new tag]             3.6.9      -> 3.6.9
 * [new tag]             4.0.0      -> 4.0.0
 * [new tag]             4.0.1      -> 4.0.1
 * [new tag]             4.0.2      -> 4.0.2
 * [new tag]             4.0.3      -> 4.0.3
 * [new tag]             4.0.4      -> 4.0.4
 * [new tag]             4.0.5      -> 4.0.5
 * [new tag]             4.0.6      -> 4.0.6
 * [new tag]             4.0.7      -> 4.0.7
 * [new tag]             4.0.8      -> 4.0.8
 * [new tag]             4.0.9      -> 4.0.9
HEAD is now at 78feddce9 Merge pull request #15044 from Homebrew/revert-15040-move_cask/cmd/reinstall
Failed during: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew update --force --quiet
```

### UPDATE

I tried again on my home network…it still doesn’t work, but does throw a different error:

```
HEAD is now at 86c518e2d Merge pull request #15007 from apainintheneck/add-service-block-to-formula-api
Failed during: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew update --force —quiet
```

Comment: Did you try to remove /opt/homebrew, ensure that there is no brew in /usr/local/bin, and then start again from scratch?

Comment: Multiple times.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/457593/9058 might help as well.

Comment: Still doesn't work, bur new error: `HEAD is now at d80f7ac48 Merge pull request #15052 from MikeMcQuaid/formulary_service`

Comment: Can you clean up everything again, create a new admin account and install from there?

Comment: If you mean create a new macos user, no. I've been in this account for 2-3 years at this point. It's not feasible to start over.

Comment: We need to figure out what is causing the problem. If it works with a new account, we know it‘s something in your existing one. If it fails as well, we know it‘s something else. I’m both cases you can roll back by removing both the Homebrew installation and the newly created user.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll try this out when I get a chance.